# Cosa significa "sororanza"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia del nuovo cognome* ho letto:

> O preferivo che lei si privasse di quella gioia, che Nino ne soffrisse, che entrambi perdessero il lume della ragione finendo non per gestire con accortezza il loro desiderio ma per esserne pericolosamente travolti? Ci fu un momento, in quella notte, in cui arrivai a pensare, a forza di seguirla lungo il filo delle sue argomentazioni, che sostenerla nell’impresa, oltre a essere un punto d’arrivo importante per la nostra lunga **sororanza**, era anche il modo di manifestare il mio amore – lei diceva amicizia, ma io disperata pensavo: amore, amore, amore – per Nino.

Ho cercato il significato di "sororanza" in alcuni dizionari, ma non l'ho trovato. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: @DenisNardin: Ho trovato questo [articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/sorellanza-universale).

Comment: Ciao,
Incredibile! Ho appena letto questo stesso pezzo e infatti anche io cercavo "sororanza"! ))
Secondo me è scritto anche un po' in dialetto perché è veramente sentita e voleva essere più "naturale" possibile. "Sor" e "Sora" a Roma si usano per signor/a.

Comment: Benvenuta/o su Italian.SE, @CelesteAgosta! Lo spazio dove hai scritto è riservato alle risposte alla domanda. Per questa ragione, il tuo post è stato convertito in un commento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La parola italiana *sorella* deriva dal diminutivo del latino *soror* (che significa per l'appunto *sorella*).

Da questo è possibile capire che *sororanza* altro non è che una forma alternativa (e leggermente arcaicizzante) per *sorellanza*, cioè "l'essere sorelle" (in questo caso in senso figurato).

Può essere utile notare che *sora* è un sinonimo di *sorella*, ancorchè poco usato, e ultimamente l'origine del termine italiano *suora*. Come osserva DaG nei commenti quest'uso è però scollegato dall'uso di *sor* e *sora* come forme regionali delle parole italiane *signor* e *signora*.

Comment: L'ultima osservazione (su “sora”) è correttissima (cf. Francesco d'Assisi), ma bisognerebbe fare una distinzione, perché nell'Italia centrale “sor” e “sora” stanno per “signore” e “signora” davanti a nomi proprî (sor Pampurio, sora Lella).

Comment: @DaG Interessante, non lo sapevo. Immagino siano simili al Veneto *sior* e *siora*. Lo aggiungo subito alla risposta

Comment: @DaG Un'ultima domanda, per pura curiosità personale. L'uso di *sora* come variante di *signora* è pronunciato come *sora=sorella* (cioè con la *o* aperta) o come il Veneto *siora* (cioè con la *o* chiusa)?

Comment: Mi dice l'orecchio, e mi conferma lo Zingarelli, che ha la *o* chiusa.

Comment: Grazie mille! Non pensavo fosse nei dizionari sennò avrei controllato. Mea culpa...

Comment: @DenisNardin A Roma pronunciamo "sor" e "sora" con la o aperta. Ho notato la stessa pronuncia nella provincia di Viterbo.

Comment: @DenisNardin: In questa lettura ad alta voce dei *[Ragazzi di vita](http://www.radio3.rai.it/dl/radio3/popupaudio.html?t=Ragazzi%20di%20vita%20-%20Lettura%20V&p=Ragazzi%20di%20vita%20-%20Lettura%20V&d=&u=http%3A%2F%2Fmediapolisvod.rai.it%2Frelinker%2FrelinkerServlet.htm%3Fcont%3DRDII1OIAoCEeeqqEEqual)* di Pasolini a me sembra sia una *o* chiusa.

Comment: Tu dici davvero “sòra Lella/Gina/...”, @Benedetta? Cioè non con la “o” di “ora” o “amore”, bensì con quella di “cuore”? Non ti confonderai con la “zia s[u]ora”?

Comment: @DaG: Anch'io sono incuriosita di questo fatto perché si suppone che nei *Ragazzi di vita* si dovrebbe avere la pronuncia di Roma.

Comment: @DaG Dico veramente "sòra Lella / sòr Mario...", e non solo io :)

Comment: Grazie, @Benedetta, sarà uno di quei casi come “colónna/colònna” etc.

Comment: Grazie a te, @DaG, che mi ci hai fatto pensare. Credo anch'io sia uno di quei casi.

Answer (score -2):

*fratellanza <==> sorellanza* 
**sorellanza** = sorellevolezza = sororanza = sororità != sororato

Comment: Purtroppo, Illy, una risposta così è meno che inutile: confonde le idee. Se hai voglia e tempo, descrivi i vari termini, più o meno moderni e usati, che sono derivati in italiano da *soror*, e il loro nesso con la domanda posta; ma così come fai, se uno non sa già di che stai parlando, è pressoché illeggibile.